Java Swing GridBagLayout not working as expected when trying to add another JPanel with its own layout and labels as part of it
I have an assigment where I need to replicate an specific layout wth JavaSwing. I decided to use GridBagLayout since it seems really flexible but it isn't responding as expected when I try to add another JPanel with its own layout as part o the grid.
The code is the following:
/*
 * GridBagLayoutDemo.java requires no other files.
 */

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JavaSwingLayout {
    final static boolean shouldFill = true;
    final static boolean shouldWeightX = true;
    final static boolean RIGHT_TO_LEFT = false;

    public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {
        if (RIGHT_TO_LEFT) {
            pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        }

        JLabel label;
        JPanel section;
        Color color;
        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        if (shouldFill) {
            // natural height, maximum width
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        }

        // Turquoise
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setOpaque(true);
        color = new Color(76, 235, 169);
        label.setBackground(color);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridheight = 4;
        c.ipadx = 150;
        c.ipady = 100;
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        pane.add(label, c);

        // Section
        section = new JPanel();
        section.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());  

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.gridheight = 4;
        c.ipadx = 0;
        c.ipady = 0;
        c.weighty = 0;
        c.weightx = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        pane.add(section, c);

        // red
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setOpaque(true);
        color = new Color(254, 0, 0);
        label.setBackground(color);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.ipadx = 50;
        c.ipady = 33;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        section.add(label, c);
        
        // orange
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        color = new Color(255, 109, 0);
        label.setBackground(color);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridheight = 2;
        c.ipadx = 0;
        c.ipady = 0;
        section.add(label, c);


        //magenta
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        color = new Color(240, 0, 255);
        label.setBackground(color);
    
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridheight = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.ipadx = 100;
        c.ipady = 100;
        section.add(label, c);
    

        // Green
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setOpaque(true);
        color = new Color(56, 120, 0);
        label.setBackground(color);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridheight = 2;
        c.ipadx = 100;
        c.ipady = 50;
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        pane.add(label, c);

        // Blue
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setOpaque(true);
        color = new Color(1, 80, 159);
        label.setBackground(color);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridheight = 5;
        c.ipady = 115;
        pane.add(label, c);
            
        // Tan
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setOpaque(true);
        color = new Color(201, 157, 97);
        label.setBackground(color);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 7;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.ipady = 25;
        pane.add(label, c);
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        // Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayoutDemo");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Set up the content pane.
        addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

        // Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        // creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}


The output comes out like this image:

But I want for the JPanel called section with its own GridBagLayout to not stretch the space between JLabels vertically like that, I want for it to ocupy the same space as the turquoise JLabel above it.
Before adding the JLabels to section JPanel it looks like this:

But after adding them it distorts the space it is supposed to ocupy and as much as I try I cant seem to fix it.

Not an answer as such, but some pointers: don't reuse GridBagConstraints instances for different components and if you want components to expand and take up all space, then you should probably not be using padding

I must say I'm not 100% sure what you want it to look like, but I think it might be more like this perhaps?

What does a correct layout look like?

@g00se It is perfectly fine to reuse a GridBagConstraints object with multiple child components.  It gets cloned with every add.  In fact, using the same GridBagConstraints can make the UI code considerably cleaner.

“I want for it to occupy the same space as the turquoise JLabel above it.”  I don’t understand this statement.  Do you want ‘section’ to always appear immediately beneath the turquoise label?

@VGR thanks for letting me know

What do you want, what is your goal?

In these cases, it's usually best to 'mock' the gui you want using a graphics program

GridBagLayout Suggestion
Try adding this to the bottom of addComponentsToPane:
for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
    pane.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(0), new GridBagConstraints(
        2, y, 0, 1, 0, 1,
        GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
        new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
}

I think you're approaching the layout like you're filling in cells on a graph paper. In order for a GridBagLayout to approach it the same way: it helps to put something on each of the 8 rows. So with this code: we're adding an empty 0x0 box on each row. This helps force the GridBagLayout to think of each row the way you're thinking about them.
With this change: the turquoise box and section should be allotted the same height. But section doesn't fill its height yet. If (?) you want it to fill that height, you can start by adding:
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
section.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
pane.add(section, c);

The border helps confirm that section is stretching to the appropriate height. Then you need to reach inside section's layout and give all of those elements a y-weight and fill so they'll stretch to fill their available space.
An Alternative Suggestion
Unless you have a compelling need to approach it this way: I recommend not using one GridBagLayout to implement this UI. GridBagLayouts can be fragile/tricky; if you modify one property of one cell it can break other cells.
If you approach this using nested panels: I think you can avoid GridBagLayouts and use its much simpler cousin the GridLayout in 2 of the 3 panels. I'd try something resembling:

First implement a 2-column panel:

JPanel outermostRow = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
outermostRow.add(createLeftColumn());
outermostRow.add(createRightColumn());


The left column could be a 2-row panel:

private static JPanel createLeftColumn() {
    JPanel returnValue = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    returnValue.add(turquoiseBox);
    returnValue.add(section);
    return returnValue;
}


The right column could use the GridBagLayout in your original code.

